# Running php scripts from secure location

Tags: apache-2.2, php

I'm new to PHP. So far I'm trying to create a login & registration system.

My goal is to have visible PHP pages and then only runnable PHP pages which sort of route traffic. I have a page `login.php` which is in the document root (`/var/www/html`).

There is a form which posts to `scripts/checklogin.php`. I set up scripts as a `location` in apache and to `deny from all`, in hopes that the PHP files in scripts would receive inputs via POSTs, process data, and then redirect accordingly via `header(...)`.

I'm getting denied access issues when the request POSTs to `scripts/checklogin.php`, which I'm guessing is due to the `deny from all`.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you *deny* access to your scripts you won't be able to access them. That's what *deny* is for. Don't do it, and you should be fine. And now seriously, why do you need the scripts to be non-accessible?

Answer (score 1):

You can put an .htaccess file in the scripts directory like that:

```
Deny from all
```

An just include the files you are going to use from your main scripts, so you cannot executem them from the browser (for example: http://localhost/scripts/test.php, will give you a 403 forbidden error); but include them, for example:

```
include("./scripts/test.php");
```

Is not denied the access; that's because they run in different layers.

I guess that was your doubt.